# Margins for proof environment

Tags: indentation, theorems

The code below is (almost) the `proof` environment of `amsthm`:

```
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]%
{%
\par\pushQED{\qed}\normalfont\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax%
\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces%
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse%
}%
```

I know how to control the left indentation  with a `\hangindent` but I would like to know how to control the `rightmargin` in a simple way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
\trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
```

to

```
\begin{list}{}{\rightmargin=...\leftmargin=...}%
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
```

and add `\end{list}` instead of `\endtrivlist` to the end of your declaration

Comment: interesting but there is still a slight spurious horizontal space that I cannot remove?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean.  Can you give a MWE?

Comment: something went wrong but I cannot reproduce it now. Your code works well. Thanks!