# Indentation for proofs

Tags: indentation, theorems

I'm using `amsbook` document class and `amsthm` package. I want the proofs to stand out from the rest of the text by slightly indenting them, i.e. leaving some margins from left and right. How do I do that?

It seems that [Margins for proof environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35198/margins-for-proof-environment) is the same question. But the code doesn't work for me, probably because I'm using `amsthm` package already.

Comment: May I ask why? It waste space and does not seem to bring anything extra to the understanding of the proof.

Comment: It's just an experiment.

Answer (score 4):

You can experiment with this modification of the `proof` environment:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \list{}{\leftmargin=4em
          \rightmargin=\leftmargin
          \settowidth{\itemindent}{\itshape#1}%
          \labelwidth=\itemindent
          % the following line is not needed with amsart, but might be with other classes
          \parsep=0pt \listparindent=\parindent 
  }
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

However it doesn't seem a good idea to me: if the proof is short it's easily recognizable anyway; if it's long, the narrow margin will spoil the page balance.

[image]

Comment: How can you make the paragraphs behave normally inside of the indented proof?

Comment: @RandyRanderson They are normally indented, as far as I can see.

Comment: Not when you use `\documentclass{report}`.

Comment: @RandyRanderson Add `\parsep=0pt \listparindent=\parindent` after `\labelwidth=\itemindent`, as I did in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{Proof}[1][Proof]
  {\proof[#1]\leftskip=1cm\rightskip=1cm}
  {\endproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}

\begin{Proof}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try with a list (`enumerate` or `itemize`) in the `Proof` environment?