# Proof environment on LaTeX

Tags: environments

I want to make a new environment in LaTeX. It'll be a proof environment (for math papers), and what I want is to indent all the paragraph. How can I do that?

I do this:

```tex
\newenvironment{proo}[1][\proofname]{\noindent\normalfont{\itshape#1{:}}\quad\mdseries\ignorespaces}  {{$\Box$}{\vskip\belowdisplayskip}}
```

Comment: see also [Indentation for proofs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62036/579), [Margins for proof environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35198/579)

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the AMS packages? I.e., `amsthm` here? It has plenty of knobs to frob. Besides, your creativity is better spent elsewhere than reinventing what experts offer as their solution. Even if it isn't perfect, it is probably what your readers are accustomed to, so it eases understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following:

```tex
\let\proofindent=20pt % or whatever you want

\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]%
{\advance\leftskip\proofindent% 
 \noindent\normalfont{\itshape#1{:}}\quad\mdseries\ignorespaces}  
{{$\Box$}{\vskip\belowdisplayskip}}
```

I just adopted part of the `\narrower` macro to give an expanded left margin.